# How to expire One-time Password after N number of attempts

Tags: java

If someone tries to login for 5 times the otp should expire when the user tries it for the 6th time.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code. Your question is so generic.

Comment: What is the otp?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the counter for each incorrect code entry and when it reaches 6 show an error

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information what your OTP system is or anything, all we can do are educated guesses.

First, I have to guess what your actual problem is, because the answer is too obvious.

You have a counter (saved whereever the OTP is saved), and for each bad attempt you add 1. When it reaches 6, you delete the OTP from the database/service/whatever, and show the user a warning that you have done so. Then you reset the counter to 0 (for the new password).

Upon successfully entering the password, you also reset the counter.